# What is the current recommended way of changing the collation of an Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

We would like to switch to using the `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8` collation in our Azure SQL database. Altering the collation of individual columns aside, if this were on-premise SQL Server 2019, changing the collation of the database would just be a matter of running `ALTER DATABASE CURRENT COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8` (with the database in single-user mode). I understand that `ALTER DATABASE` with `COLLATE` is not supported on Azure SQL, the collation can only be set when the database is created. I found [this workaround](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5530/how-to-change-an-azure-sql-database-collation/) from 2 years ago, but exporting the entire database to on-premise and importing it back to Azure seems impractical for a large production database. Are there any other ways of doing it as of now?